# Edittext resizes in landscape mode when softkeyboard appears

Tags: android

When I'm in landscape mode with an EditText on the screen, if I tap in the EditText to bring up the soft keyboard, the EditText expands in both dimensions to take up the entire screen not occupied by the keyboard!     It returns to normal size when the keyboard is dismissed.

I've examined other commercial apps on my phone and many (but not all!) of them do the same thing.   The EditText is in a TableRow, in a TableLayout and looks like this:

```
  android:id="@+id/editTextHeight"
  android:layout_width="100dp" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:maxLength="25"
  android:hint="Height"
```

(Android 2.2, Droid Incredible, FWIW) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You need to add `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` to prevent this behavior.

You can read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions

Comment: Thanks!!  That worked.    I noticed the resizing-to-fill-up-the-available-screen" behavior on many of the commercial applications I've installed which made me wonder if it was a bug or an intentional feature.  I perceived it as a bug in my app.   Thanks again!

Comment: Is there a way to set this as default for the whole application? I think the exception case should be the other way around with something like `flagExtractUI`