# Android EditText expands to dialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, landscape, expand

I have this layout

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/viewer_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/viewer_filter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_filter"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true" >
            </EditText>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/viewer_filterX"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/viewer_filter"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/viewer_filter"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </ImageView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/viewer_search"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_search"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true" >
            </EditText>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/viewer_searchGo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/viewer_search"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/viewer_search"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </ImageView>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/viewer_searchX"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/viewer_search"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/viewer_searchGo"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
                android:visibility="invisible" >
            </ImageView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/viewer_hscroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/viewer_top" >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/viewer_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I click on either EditText it expands to this dialog:

[image]

On portrait mode the EditTexts can be edited as they are without expanding. The XML for portrait is similar, only the EditTexts are one below the other and are screen wide.

How do I prevent this EditText expansion?
Not only the full phone screen is hidden by the EditText + virtual keyboard, but the clickable images the I put over the EditText are not visible.

- I tried to set the EditText layout_width to 0dp, but they don't show.
- I am not using SearchViews because they steal the focus and I cannot use the back key to go back to the previous activity.

**Update**
I removed the layout-land XML and used the same XML for both portrait and landscape.
In portrait mode it is fine, no expansion, in landscape mode there is expansion.
So it has to do somehow with being in landscape mode.

Comment: create a layout for landscape

Comment: @shreeshas This is the layout for landscape, I wrote that the XML for portrait is similar, but different.

Comment: hi try with   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" parameter in your manifest file

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys I posted the solution, it is an IME property.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

add this line to your edit text

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
```

edit text look like this

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/viewer_filter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="hint_filter"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true" 
                android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `android:maxLines="1"` for `EditText`

Comment: Tried it just now, no change

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. You can use mEditText.setSingleLine(true); where you are using it. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Tried is as setSingleLine() and also setSingleLine(true), no change

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889853/edittext-resizes-in-landscape-mode-when-softkeyboard-appears) addresses the same problem and has the solution

Need to add

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```

to prevent this behavior.

If someone knows how, please mark this post as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please add this line in java code  where your edit text is declared **description.setMaxLines(1);**

Comment: This solution was posted already, does not work. ::: I posted already the correct solution.